# Knee mesh broken when applying animation (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, mesh

Pardon my bad English.
I've been working with Unity for a while, but it's my first time using humanoid animation on human body.
When applying the crouching animation to the rigged model,
the knee parts broken when overlapping each other (Please refer to the image).

[Broken knee image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H18jO.png)

I want to make the animation work on the model, if it's possible,
by bending the inner parts of the knee, or maybe any other way possible to make the knee smoother.

Is there any way to fix this on Unity without modifying the original rigged fbx?

Comment: That looks very much like a skinning issue for the knee. That is not fixable in Unity and would require correcting the skinning of the original FBX.

Answer (score 0):

Definitaly a skin weighing issue. You can modify the weights for each bone easily enough with any 3D program such as Blender, altought that would require for you to modify the original fbx.